# TypeError: str object is not callable

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
fi=tarfile.open(os.path.join(pathin,file_in),'r')
list-fi.getmembers()
entries_list[]
for lis in list:
    name_list=lis.name()
    entries_list.append(name_list)
print entries_list.
```

At the line `name_list=lis.name()`, I'm getting the error `str object is not callable`.  Could you explain why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something must have gone wrong while copying your code.  Lines like `list-fi.getmembers()` and `entries_list[]` don't make sense.

Answer (score 6):

`lis.name` is a string, so `lis.name()` tries to call this string.  Because strings aren't callable, you get the error `str object is not callable`.

Comment: si what must i do to get rid from the error. im very new to python and infact programming.. pls help

Comment: @user1240863: Don't call it.  Simply use `lis.name`.