# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable -what have i done wrong?

Tags: python

im not sure - i searched over an hour how to solve it. I rewrite the code 4 times but it still wont work - at all, its a realy simple code but i dont know how the failure has happen.

Code:

```
pin = '4372'
konto = '5000'
pin_s = False
kontostand = False

while pin_s == False:
    pin_e = input ("Bitte geben Sie ihren Pin ein: ")
    if pin == pin_e:
        pin_s = True
    else:
        pin_s = False

print ("Ihr Kontostand beträgt: ", konto)

while kontostand == False:
    geld_a = input("Bitte geben sie den Betrag ein den sie abheben möchten: ")
    if geld_a > konto:
        print("Ihr Kontostand reicht nicht aus. Er beträgt: ", konto,"€")
        print("Bitte wählen sie einen anderen Betrag.")
    else:
        kontostand = True

print ("Sie heben ", geld_a ("€ ab"))
print ("Ihr neuer Kontostand beträgt: "), konto - geld_a ("€")
```

The Error happens in line 23
I totally cant see what i have made wrong, especially its really simple. i started with c++ but for my university i have to start with python now.

So... can someone eventually tell me where is the failure? :(

Comment: `geld_a ("€ ab")` is one of your issues, you are trying to call a string.

Comment: maybe my english is too bad for that. But what exactly you mean?

Comment: `geld_a` is a string containing whatever text the user entered. It is not a function, but you are trying to call it as if it were one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: str object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570593/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: when i do print(geld_a) it works and i dont get an error? But it doesnt work when i do print ("Sie heben", geld_a ("€ ab")

Comment: Because you are allowed to print strings but you are not allowed to "call" them like they are a function.

Comment: yea -i  just wanted to print it, but it doesnt work

Comment: Why did you add the `("€ ab")` part in the 2nd example? That makes it like calling a function. What did you expect that to do?

Answer (score 1):

You're using your parentheses wrong. It appears you want to append one string to another for printing, but instead it's being interpreted as a function call. Use commas instead:

```
print ("Sie heben ", geld_a, "€ ab")
```

Answer (score 1):

Google translate helped with the context a bit. I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
print("Sie heben {} (€ ab)".format(geld_a))
```

or

```
print("Sie heben " + str(geld_a) + "(€ ab)")
```

As others have said parenthesis () denote a method call but a string is not a method.